# Cakephp, how to create grid and list view using pagination?

Tags: php, listview, cakephp, gridview, pagination

What i intend to do is change view(grid or list) with cakephp.
So what i've done was this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".lista_options #gridview").click(function(){
        $( "#content" ).addClass( 'cubos' );


    });

    $(".lista_options #listview").click(function(){
    $( "#content" ).removeClass( 'cubos' );


    });
});
```

The problem here is that i have a paginator, and for that reason when i change page to get more results the view that i choose doesn't stays. My question how can i change my view mode and be constant during all pagination?

Any suggestion is good. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Share your changes using cookies and (or) sessions. When you click to switch between list and grid, save changes to the cookie, on page load read the cookie and uses its value.

**EDIT:**  update code

use this [jquery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

in your javascript add:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".lista_options #gridview").click(function(){
    $( "#content" ).addClass( 'cubos' );
    $.cookie.raw = true;
    $.cookie('CakeCookie[switch]', 'grid', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

});

$(".lista_options #listview").click(function(){
$( "#content" ).removeClass( 'cubos' );
    $.cookie.raw = true;
    $.cookie('CakeCookie[switch]', 'list', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

});
});
```

AppController::beforeFilter();

```
if($this->Cookie->check('switch')){
  $this->set('style', $this->Cookie->read('switch'));
}
```

index.ctp

```
<div class="<?php if($style == 'grid'){ ?> cubos <?php } ?>" > ...
```

Comment: Do you have any link where it explains where to do that? Is ther in cakebook?